# Getting empty response while fetching resource using cURL

Tags: curl, access-token

I'm getting empty response while I'm trying to access the resource using access token in curl. Can somebody correct me if my command is wrong ?

Here is my command:

curl -k https://10.129.137.151:5060/getAccountInfo -H "Authorization:Bearer AAEYbXlyZWdpc3RlcmVkX29hdXRoY2xpZW50rvvSQ7kHkrOiiVTyvnnCBWhv4U7dKMJCsGEnjzu+awG1lZC9GVBq1H3tY+vGLdl+cyvmkKwUY3tRU36NNFDq0tl6WTDuiVr0hJdlaScwMu7p6PIPD2u5NQULzR+djc3z"

I'm not even getting any error message after entering the above command.

Thankyou in advance !

Comment: add `-v` what do you get?

Comment: I tried giving -v after -k but it did not work.

Comment: ... sure it didn't work, but now curl printed debug messages, what are those debug messages?